# linux ' top ' get total of a user's cpu usage > 100%, with IRIX mode off

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

I used ' **top -bn 1 -u myaccount**' to monitor the summary of all the cpu usage of my account.

But sometimes my log shows that the summary adds up to 160% plus.
I'm quite confused, does anybody know why?

my top version is 3.2.3

here's my top of my toprc:

RCfile for "top with windows"       # shameless braggin'

Id:a, Mode_altscr=0, Mode_irixps=0, Delay_time=3.000, Curwin=0

========

**Irix mode on:**

PID   %CPU
18119  4.3   162:36.22 java

**Irix mode off:**

PID   %CPU  (8 cores machine)
18119  0.6   162:36.22 java

I mean in the second condition , all my process's cpu usage sometimes may add up to 160%

Comment: multicore machine?

Comment: yes, a group of machines, 4-8cores

Answer (score 3):

jørgensen explained the CPU usage higher than 100%. Basically, CPU usage is scaled to be 100% at full use of one core. The IRIX mode for top just changes the way the CPU usage is calculated.

The IRIX mode is explained on the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top), which says:

> k: %CPU -- CPU usage
>       The task's share of the elapsed CPU time since the last screen update, expressed as a percentage of total CPU time. In a true SMP
>   environment, if 'Irix mode' is Off, top will operate in 'Solaris mode'
>   where a task's cpu usage will be divided by the total number of CPUs.
>   You toggle 'Irix/Solaris' modes with the 'I' interactive command.

and

> 'I' :Irix/Solaris_Mode_toggle
>       When operating in 'Solaris mode' ('I' toggled Off), a task's cpu usage will be divided by the total number of CPUs. After issuing this
>   command, you'll be informed of the new state of this toggle.

Here is some additional information on top: [Analyzing thread CPU usage on Linux](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/tools/topic/com.ibm.java.doc.igaa/_1vg0001475cb4a-1190e2e0f74-8000_1007.html).

Answer (score 1):

That is the answer then. Each thread can be scheduled and max out a different CPU, and since top shows processes instead, it can easily add up.

Comment: Could you please explain it more clearly please? I wonder why when irix mode is truned off, cpu usage can add up to over 100%.